# How to run function after another object reaches certain state

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have a game. I have 3 files app.js, game.js, modal.js. 
The Modal sets an event listener on the 'next' button of the modal, and keeps track of 'currentStep'. That is, the modal has multiple steps. Now, I want in the app.js file to start the game, only after the user has completed the modal. In my modal I have :

```
constructor(){
    this.currentStep = 0;

}
complete() {
    return (this.currentStep >= 4 ? true : false);
}

activate() {
   ....



    nextButton.addEventListener( 'click' , (e) => {

       if (this.currentStep === 0) {
          firstInstructions.classList.add('hideMe');
          firstGif.classList.remove("hideMe");  
          ....    
       }else if (this.currentStep === 4) {
          modal.classList.add("hideMe");
       }
    this.currentStep++;
});
```

}

Now, the basic point is that I somehow want to let my app.js know when the user has completed the Modal so that I can run game.play();
So something like :

```
 const game = new Game();
 const modal = new Modal();
 modal.activate();

 // game.play() WHEN modal.complete
```

Can someone suggest the proper way for the Modal to let the App know that it is complete, whenever that happens. I know I can use a while loop and keep checking if modal.complete() and when it is run game.play() but that seems wrong. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways, one is you can just add in the activate the game itself like this.

```
const game = new Game();
const modal = new Modal();
modal.activate(game);
```

Then in the activate you can do this:

```
activate (game) {
   ....



   nextButton.addEventListener( 'click' , (e) => {

     if (this.currentStep === 0) {
       firstInstructions.classList.add('hideMe');
       firstGif.classList.remove("hideMe");  
       ....    
     } else if (this.currentStep === 4) {
       modal.classList.add("hideMe");

       // Put it here
       game.play();
     }
  this.currentStep++;
};
```

That is if the last modal step will start the game. But if you really want to put it in complete method. You can also do this

```
const game = new Game();
// put the game inside the Modal constructor
const modal = new Modal(game);
modal.activate();
```

Then you put the game in the constructor method

```
constructor (game) {
  this.currentStep = 0;
  // put it here
  this._game = game;
}
```

Then in the complete method you can just invoke play from the game

```
complete () {
  this._game.play();
  return (this.currentStep >= 4 ? true : false);
}
```

Hope this helps